# CRM 2011 SDK MetadataDiagram Console Application

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

Is there anyone who is aware or have used the console application (**MetadataDiagram**) provided by *SDK* in **MSCRM 2011** ?

I have executed this app for my CRM which contains around 230 entities.

It's execution still in continue mode from last 24 hour and of course, it is progressing slowly that is why I am not able to stop it.

Am I doing anything wrong or usually this happens ?

Your inputs are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done to stop it? And when you say "not able to stop it" do you still see the console window?

Comment: I just closed the Console window to stop the execution. Console window is displaying the progress of entities which are covered for the diagram.. After I stopped it, I found the vsd diagram in bin folder but it was containing almost 250 entities.